# Minimum number of coins - (dynamic programming solution - topdown approach)

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, programming-challenge, dynamic-programming

This is a problem from [topcoder tutorials](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=dynProg)

> Given a list of N coins, their values (V1, V2, ... , VN), and the total sum S. Find the minimum number of coins the sum of which is S (we can use as many coins of one type as we want), or report that it's not possible to select coins in such a way that they sum up to S.

This is my first attempt at a DP solution. Did I do it right? How to make this code better, faster and less ugly? Is there a better solution than what I did?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

int coins_td(std::vector<int>& v, int n, std::set<int>& s);

int coins_td(int n, std::set<int>& s) {
    std::vector<int> coins(n+1, -1);
    coins[0] = 0;
    return coins_td(coins, n, s);
}

int coins_td(std::vector<int>& v, int n, std::set<int>& s) {
    static const int coin = 1;
    if (n < 0) {
        return -2;
    }
    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (v[n] != -1) {
        return v[n];
    }
    int tcoins = coin+coins_td(v, n-*s.begin(), s);
    for (auto i = s.rbegin(); i != s.rend(); ++i) {
        if (n >= *i) {
            tcoins = std::min(tcoins, coin+coins_td(v, n-*i, s));
            break;
        }
    }
    v[n] = tcoins;
    return tcoins;
}

int main() {
    int value;
    std::cin >> value;
    if (value <= 0) {
        std::cout << value << '\n';
    } else {
        std::set<int> values;
        int v;
        while (std::cin >> v) {
            values.insert(v);
        }
        int result = coins_td(value, values);
        if (result == 0) {
            std::cout << "it's not possible to select coins in such a way that they sum up to " << value << "." << '\n';
        } else {
            std::cout << result << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `main`

> ```
>     if (value <= 0) {
>         std::cout << value << '\n';
> ```

This seems to be an error condition.  You might consider using `std::cerr` instead:

```
        std::cerr << "Value must be positive.  You provided:  " << value << '\n';
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
```

This also adds an error message so that we don't have to read the code to try to figure out why it is printing a value to the screen.

The explicit `return` allows us to return something different for the error condition than for a successful run.  Once we have it, we can get rid of the `else` clause and just proceed with the rest of the block.

> ```
>         if (result == 0) {
> ```

I'd tend to make this `<= 0` instead.  Only positive values are correct.  In fact, I might switch the logic around the other way:

```
    if ( 0 < result ) {
        std::cout << "The minimum number of coins that sum to " << value << " is " << result << ".\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "It's not possible to select coins in such a way that they sum up to " << value << ".\n";
    }
```

I find it easier to follow to make the failure case the `else` (except for an early `return` as used prior).  I also added more of a message in the case of success.

### Naming

> ```
> int coins_td(std::vector<int>& v, int n, std::set<int>& s);
> ```

The input is described as a desired sum, S, and a list of coin values, V1..VN.  So I would expect a `vector` named `v` to refer to that input value.  However, in this case, `v` holds an intermediate result and `s` holds the coin values.  The desired value is in `n`.  It would be reasonable to use the same names as in the problem statement.  Normally if you change them, you'd change them to be more descriptive, e.g. `desired_sum` and `coin_values`.

What is a `coins_td`?  I've been looking at this problem for some time now, and I still have no idea.  It's possible that I'm just being slow, but this suggests to me that it is a non-descriptive name.  Writing it out rather than abbreviating might help.

> ```
>     static const int coin = 1;
> ```

While it's good that you're trying to avoid magic numbers in your code, this is a bit confusing.  What is `coin` and why does it equal `1`?  I actually think that using the value `1` is more obvious about what is happening in this case.

### Correctness

> ```
> for (auto i = s.rbegin(); i != s.rend(); ++i) {
>     if (n >= *i) {
>         tcoins = std::min(tcoins, coin+coins_td(v, n-*i, s));
>         break;
>     }
> }
> ```

This is not correct because it stops at the first one rather than the smallest one.  Consider a desired value of 7 with coin values of 1, 3, 4, and 5.  This code would return an answer of 3 (for 1+1+5), but the correct answer is 2 (4+3).  You should remove the `break` statement.

> ```
>     int tcoins = coin+coins_td(v, n-*s.begin(), s);
> ```

This is incorrect because it is possible that there may be no way to reach the value `n-*s.begin()` in which case it will return -1, which will be smaller than any of the correct values.  Instead, set it to a number *larger* than the maximum possible value:

```
int tcoins = n + 1;
```

That will make the loop logic work consistently.

> ```
>     if (n < 0) {
>         return -2;
>     }
> ```

Same thing here.  You should return a *large* number, not a small one.  That will also fix the problem of this being a magic number based on the fact that `1 + -2 = -1` where `-1` is your magic value for an unset entry in `v`.

```
    if (n < 0) {
        return std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    }
```

More info on [`std::numeric_limits`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1855465/2625983).  Or leave this off entirely, as in the current code, this should never happen.  It only happens in the original code because of initializing `tcoins` without checking that its possible.

```
std::vector<int> coins(n+1, -1);
```

And again here.

> ```
>     if (n == 0) {
>         return 0;
>     }
>     if (v[n] != -1) {
>         return v[n];
>     }
> ```

These are redundant.  Since `v[0] = 0`, the second `if` will have the same effect as the first when `n == 0`.

```
    if ( v[n] <= n ) {
        return v[n];
    }
```

Or

```
    if ( v[n] < std::numeric_limits<int>::max() ) {
        return v[n];
    }
```

Either should work fine.  Note that a valid `v[n]` can't be greater than `n` because the coin values are positive integers (or at least I think that they should be).